# Semantic UI modal set max-width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/eq2kyprs/3/

How can I set the following on the semantic UI modal window in the jsfiddle above?

```
width:100%
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
max-width:300px;
```

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/definition

Answer (score -1):

will find sample of modal semantic 
 https://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/jwrLJd

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  $('#demo-show-small').on('click', function() {
    $('#demo-small-modal').modal('show');
  });

  $('#demo-show-long').on('click', function() {
    $('#demo-long-modal').modal('show');
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to specify exact CSS properties as listed.